# Is there a way on lichess to see the Correspondence chess rankings?

Tags: lichess

Lichess has leaderboards for every variant of chess and also every single time control of the standard variant except for Correspondence chess. Does anybody know where to see the leaderboard for Correspondence chess on Lichess and if so how?

Comment: I cant see LI since they screwed up the new system.  But I suspect you can still post a question in their forum to get an answer.  Or you could ask the honchos at LI.   I suspect they do not have a leaderboard for correspondence at this time.

Comment: @yobamamama It is very weird, but I am just interested if you happen to know a very high rated player for correspondence on Lichess? I saw that many of the top players on Lichess don't even play Correspondence.

Comment: I do not know who plays correspondence on LI.  I do know that some people do play slow.  And I have not seen any correspondence rankings before my PC stopped working with them after their big change that stopped my chrome from working.

Comment: @PhishMaster I forgot to accept some of them since I don't spend too much time on Stackexchange, but I don't want you to get the impression that I don't like your answers. I do upvote nearly all of them and find the information helpful. It's ofcourse up to you on whether you want to write up answers for me or not.

Comment: @Phismaster Sorry for not accepting your answers. I have gone back and accepted your answers.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate it, and I am glad to answer your questions. I just felt like you had something against me.

Comment: @SubhanKhan I just want to make one thing clear: I did not want you to think that you HAVE to accept my answers, especially not right away, but I do appreciate it, and thank you for that. Again, I thought, incorrectly, that maybe it was personal at first. I do think that it is important for people to accept answers IF they think they are good enough, and if you pick another answer, that is fine too. I am just glad that you are now in the habit of at least thinking about it. And, the place has been dead except for you lately, so thanks for the good questions.

Comment: @PhishMaster Good evening! Your answer is not working anymore! Do you have another magic solution?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is funny that they do not have it listed [here](https://lichess.org/player), as you mentioned.

I just took a guess, and changed the end of the URL to "correspondence", and got the top 200 just like the others.

https://lichess.org/player/top/200/correspondence

Comment: Typical of too many web sites.  If you know how to drill down you can find stuff that is not obvious from other paths.

Comment: The solution is not working at 2/26/2022.