# Is there a Correspondence Chess ranking on Lichess.org on 2022?

Tags: engines, computer-chess, lichess, correspondence-chess, chess.com

A similar question was posted in the past (2020):
[Is there a way on lichess to see the Correspondence chess rankings?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/27889/is-there-a-way-on-lichess-to-see-the-correspondence-chess-rankings)

However, that solution is not working anymore. In my perspective, things have changed and lichess.org is allowing correspondence chess, but a ranking does not exist anymore. Is there a way to be certain about this topic?

Also, why lichess.org is treating correspondence chess differently, if that is the case? I am guessing  that is difficult to control who is cheating and who is not. In the past I used to play correspondence chess, but I am playing classic games now. According lichess.org classic are games that each side has 30 minutes or more for the entire game. Correspondence chess you have 1 day per move or more. Chess.com calls correspondence daily chess.

Comment: Interesting. Have you asked their staff directly? Maybe it's temporarily broken, or maybe people just don't bother with correspondence. Who knows if their anti-cheat system even bothers with correspondence

Comment: Interesting suggestion! Thank you for your thoughts!

Comment: You can ask on their GitHub or forums. I'm not sure if the forums is the place where developers respond

Comment: Very useful ideas!

Comment: It seems this topic was treated on reddit six (!) years ago: https://www.reddit.com/r/chess/comments/3zfrhq/on_lichess_why_people_doesnt_seem_to_be/

Comment: @emdio Excellent link! Maybe you should post an answer with it. However, as that was 6 years ago, who knows what is going on in 2022.

Comment: Nobody has posted an answer. If you post the answer analyzing that link, I would gladly accept it. I have a bounty on this question and it will expire soon

Comment: there's a reputation on chess.com that correspondence chess is just stockfish vs stockfish. when I played correspondence 11 years ago I think all my opponents were legit. maybe cheating is more rampant nowadays

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although it's from six years ago, the lack of leaderboards for correspondence chess in lichess was explained by its creator in [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/chess/comments/3zfrhq/on_lichess_why_people_doesnt_seem_to_be/).

Quoting from reddit's user ornicar2 (who is labeled as lichess creator):

"We don't have correspondence leaderboards because it's impossible to accurately monitor for cheating. While player behaviors are analyzable and somehow predictable in timed games, go figure what happens when a player spends 24h between two moves."

Comment: ornicar is Thibault Duplessis, creator of lichess